# How do I pull a featured image from a WordPress feed/post?

Tags: feeds

I have a Drupal 7 website. I'm already using Feeds and Feeds Importe modules to pull a feed from a WordPress website. I'm interested in a particular category, for example:

```
domainname.com/blog/category/obesity/feed
```

I added a featured image to a post. I used this plugin to add the featured image to the rss feed http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-featured-image-to-rss-feed/

How can I pull the featured image from the feed and post it as a thumbnail image by the teaser text on the Drupal website?

Comment: There is no image field in [standard RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#hrelementsOfLtitemgt). Not to mention many RSS versions in use. Thus, answer is dependent on exact module you are using to create image in RSS and will not be useful for most of the other users.

Comment: I disagree.  Wordpress to Drupal migrations are fairly common; this post could help someone in the future.

Comment: @leonel  Could you post an <item> or two so we can see what is there?